# ng-repeat performance over thousands of elements without limit filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

I'm generating a SVG graph in an [Angular](http://angularjs.org) template based on an array of the following format:

`[{x: 0, y: 1}, {x: 1, y: 2}, ...]` -- The array will contain thousands of points.

While I can quickly render a `<path>` element with thousands of points, unacceptable performance occurs when I use `ng-repeat` to create a `<circle>` element for each point.

**To ensure that the performance was not due to SVG performance**, I copied the angular generated SVG output and created a static .html file that included about 5 graphs containing about 10,000 `<circle>` elements. The static file is rendered almost instantly. I also confirmed that it's not my boiler plate code for generating and scaling points because without the `<circle>` elements (only 2 `<path>` elements) performance is exceptional.

I've narrowed it down to either `ng-repeat`'s DOM injection mechanics or the fact that `ng-repeat` creates a child scope for each element with its own dirty checking watchers. Based on some exhaustive research it appears it's more likely the latter.

Here's the template that generates the graph:

```
<svg width="1020" height="220">
    <g class="series" transform="translate(10,10)">
        <path class="series-fill" d="{{ series.path('fill') }}" stroke="none" fill="#ddd"></path>
        <path class="series-path" d="{{ series.path('line') }}" stroke="#999" stroke-width="1" fill="none"></path>
        <g class="series-points" stroke-width="1" stroke="#fff">
            <circle ng-repeat="point in points" class="series-point" r="2" cx="{{ point.scaledX }}" cy="{{ point.scaledY }}"></circle>                                                                                           
        </g>

    </g>
</svg>
```

TL;DR, What is the most Angular or recommended way to use `ng-repeat`-like behavior without dirty checking on each element or without creating a new child scope with watchers. Obviously paging/infinite scroll doesn't apply here.

Comment: I think this is going to fall under the rule of "just because you can, doesn't mean you should". In a situation like this, why not just use D3 and create a directive to inject the rendered output?

Comment: I can use D3, I'm just exploring the possibilities of using Angular as purely as I can to approach this problem. Seems like a JS framework should have some way of approaching very large data sets with a focus on performance.

Comment: There's nothing in Angular I know of for a one way template. You could write your own ng-repeat directive to simply generate the HTML without a scope, and eliminate that performance bottleneck.

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this!" "So…don't do that!" Instead of creating thousands of circles, create a `<path>` or `<polyline>` with thousands of points and use SVG markers to draw circles at each point. You're basically saying, _"I've proved that AngularJS is slow for this. I think that it shouldn't be, except that it is. How do I make it not be slow, even though it is?"_ Sometimes the tool you _want_ to use for the job isn't the _right_ tool for the job, no matter how much you want to use it.

Comment: As a note...I'm not sure if this will help performance, but I could recommend using the `ng-attr` binding for your circle attributes. I built a drawing tool using D3 and Angular and there were a lot of DOM errors with some of those attributes not being valid numbers due to the SVG spec (because Angular hadn't compiled the bindings yet). That might help your performance, but I'm not sure. Worth a shot, though. (Your path won't be affected because the `d` attribute will take a string.) If the issue is indeed DOM mechanics, this should fix that.

Comment: Out of curiousity, are you using `ngAnimate`? I've noticed that the inclusion of `ngAnimate` in angular 1.2-rc2 causes poor performance for me with `ngRepeat`, even if I didn't add any animations to the repeating items (see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3613#issuecomment-24374809)